# Parameter \newcommand tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I need to do a series of gear-trains and I have done used `\newcommand` to parametrize the gears. I am sure that it is possible to do this in a more efficient manner and would be helpful of anyone could help me with a nicer code. it is already much better that doning it line by line.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta}


% inputs are x, y , diameter of gear
\newcommand{\mygear}[3]{
\draw[very thick] (#1-0,#2+#3/2+0.1) -- (#1-0,#2+0.1);
\draw[very thick] (#1-0.1,#2+#3/2+0.1) -- (#1+0.1,#2+#3/2+0.1);
\draw[very thick] (#1-0.2,#2+0.1) -- (#1+0.2,#2+0.1);
% center of gear
\draw[very thick] (#1-0.2,#2-0.1) -- (#1+0.2,#2-0.1);
\draw[very thick] (#1-0.1,#2-#3/2-0.1) -- (#1+0.1,#2-#3/2-0.1);
\draw[very thick] (#1-0,#2-#3/2-0.1) -- (#1-0,#2-0.1);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[blue]

\mygear{1}{5}{2}
\mygear{1}{7.8}{3}
\mygear{2}{5.8}{2}
\mygear{2}{3}{3}

\draw (1,5) -- (1.5,5) |- (2,5.8);
\draw (1,7.8) -- (3,7.8) -- (3,3) -| (2,3);



    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question cannot be answered as such, since it is a matter of taste which approach to use. You could try using a pic, which allows you to apply styles easily and fits nicly into the Ti*k*Z environment, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    gear upper/.style={
        very thick
    },
    gear lower/.style={
        very thick
    },
    pics/gear/.style={code={
        \draw[pic actions, gear upper] 
            (0,#1/2+0.1) -- (0,0.1)
            (-0.1,#1/2+0.1) -- (0.1,#1/2+0.1)
            (-0.2,0.1) -- (0.2,0.1);
        % center of gear
        \draw[pic actions, gear lower] 
            (-0.2,-0.1) -- (0.2,-0.1)
            (-0.1,-#1/2-0.1) -- (0.1,-#1/2-0.1)
            (-0,-#1/2-0.1) -- (0,-0.1);
    }}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blue]

\pic at (1,5) {gear={2}};
\pic at (1,7.8) {gear={3}};
\pic[red] at (2,5.8) {gear={2}};
\pic[red, gear lower/.append style={densely dotted}] at (2,3) {gear={3}};

\draw (1,5) -- (1.5,5) |- (2,5.8);
\draw (1,7.8) -- (3,7.8) -- (3,3) -| (2,3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using this approach, you can even add a coordinate to the pic that you can later use as anchor:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    gear upper/.style={
        very thick
    },
    gear lower/.style={
        very thick
    },
    pics/gear/.style={code={
        \draw[pic actions, gear upper] 
            (0,#1/2+0.1) -- (0,0.1)
            (-0.1,#1/2+0.1) -- (0.1,#1/2+0.1)
            (-0.2,0.1) -- (0.2,0.1);
        % center of gear
        \coordinate (-center) at (0,0);
        \draw[pic actions, gear lower] 
            (-0.2,-0.1) -- (0.2,-0.1)
            (-0.1,-#1/2-0.1) -- (0.1,-#1/2-0.1)
            (0,-#1/2-0.1) -- (0,-0.1);
    }}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blue]

\pic (gear-1) at (1,5) {gear={2}};
\pic (gear-2) at (1,7.8) {gear={3}};
\pic[red] (gear-3) at (2,5.8) {gear={2}};
\pic[red, gear lower/.append style={densely dotted}] (gear-4) at (2,3) {gear={3}};

\draw (gear-1-center) -- ++(0.5,0) |- (gear-3-center);
\draw (gear-2-center) -- ++(2,0) |- (gear-4-center);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output is the same as above.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable information. I didn't know of this option before.